# Jquery jump from autocomplete onselected item to next input that is in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

this is my html form:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
 <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" id="divprecio">
<input placeholder="0,0" class="form-control" id="articulo_precio" type="text">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2" id="divcantidad">
<input min="1" max="100" class="form-control" name="articulo[cant]" id="articulo_cant" type="number">
</div>
</div>
```

i need that when i select the item in autocomplete i jump(focus) to the next input that is in the next div (divprecio), this ir my try, but is not working

from autcomplete select item function:

```
$(this).parent().next('#divcantidad').focus();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to your autocomplete input then use this to detect the autocomplete

```
$("#YourAutocompleteInputIDHere").autocomplete({  
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#divcantidad").focus();
    }
});
```